# Automatically adding folders to the Deployable zip when build using Maven

Tags: java, maven, mule

I have a pom.xml which is automatically adding src/main/resources folder.

Q1.But i have not mentioned it anywhere in my pom.xml?

Q2.I needed to add an Extra Resource Folder(Ex:src/main/cxf) folder as an additional resources folder.But not sure how to add it?

This is my pom.xml.

Note:I analyzed a bit and believe something with **build helper maven plugin**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>ops</artifactId>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <mule.version>3.7.0</mule.version>
        <eclipsePluginVersion>2.8</eclipsePluginVersion>
        <jdkName>jdk1.7.0_45</jdkName>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <junit.version>4.9</junit.version>
        <munit.version>1.1.0</munit.version>
        <mule.munit.support.version>3.7.1</mule.munit.support.version> 
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.6,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>attach-test-resources</goal>
                                            <goal>filter-resources</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore/>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-resource</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-resource</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-deployable</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>deployable</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>target</directory>
                                        <includes>
                                            <include>*.zip</include>
                                        </includes>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-mule-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeMuleDependencies>false</excludeMuleDependencies>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                    <!-- <outputDirectory>deployable</outputDirectory>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName> -->
                    <inclusions>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-extensions-support</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-extensions-spring-support</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                    </inclusions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <followSymLinks>false</followSymLinks>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${env.MULE_HOME}\apps</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>${project.artifactId}.*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                    <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${eclipsePluginVersion}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- by default download all sources when generating project files -->
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.mule.MuleServer</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-config</argument>
                        <argument>src/main/app/mule-config.xml</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${surefire.argLine}</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>replace</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <basedir>target/classes</basedir>
                    <filesToInclude>*.xml</filesToInclude>
                    <replacements>
                        <replacement>
                            <token>\/current\/</token>
                            <value>/3.3/</value>
                        </replacement>
                        <replacement>
                            <token>CE-3\.4\.0</token>
                            <value>CE-3.3.1</value>
                        </replacement>
                    </replacements>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${munit.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <coverage>
                        <runCoverage>true</runCoverage>
                        <formats>
                            <format>html</format>
                        </formats>
                    </coverage>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/munit</directory>
            </testResource>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>



    <dependencies>

        <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Xml configuration -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mule Transports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-jms</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-quartz</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-email</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-transport-ftp</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Mule Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-client</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-management</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-sxc</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mockobjects</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockobjects-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.09</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- project Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lp.mule</groupId>
            <artifactId>cipher</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-mule</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20131018</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-ws</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-munit-support</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.munit.support.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
            <version>${munit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-extensions-support</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-module-extensions-spring-support</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>                    
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Snapshots Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>LP01DevContDlv-ext</id>
            <name>LP01DevContDlv-ext-releases</name>
            <url>http://artifactory.corp.local.com/artifactory/ext-release-local</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>LP01DevContDlv-libs</id>
            <name>LP01DevContDlv-libs-releases</name>
            <url>http://artifactory.corp.local.com/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>codehaus-mule-repo</id>
            <name>codehaus-mule-repo</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-release</id>
            <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

`src/main/resources` is a default resource directory as per Maven conventions. So anything in `src/main/resources` will end up in the resultant jar file - The maven resources plugin will copy/filter these to `target/classes` directory which gets packaged later on.

If you want to add additional resource directories, then have a look at the [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html)

```
 <build>
   ...
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/main/cxf</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
   ...
 </build>
```

The build helper plugin's [add-resource mojo](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/add-resource-mojo.html) can also add extra resource directories, but in this case it should be easier to declare an extra resource directory in the build section as mentioned in the Maven resource plugin's documentation.

Comment: I understand your point,but src/main/resources is not getting added to one of my projects with the above pom.xml. I am not sure why its not getting addded